# I want to update part of an email in SFMC using restAPI

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest

I am looking at updating only part of an existing email using the following Rest API call.

https://et_subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/

I am able to update all the content but I just want to change a part of the content. e.g an updated variable string.